# Позади пустой перрон, свидание с прошлым(,) словно сон

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить это предложение из песни «Свидание с прошлым» Михаила Боярского?

> Позади пустой перрон, свидание с прошлым, словно сон.

> Позади пустой перрон — свидание с прошлым, словно сон.

> Позади пустой перрон, свидание с прошлым словно сон.